# Check if something is not a directory in Linux

Tags: shell

I am trying to write an if statement where it will go to the next iteration of the for loop if `i` is the variable or if `i` is a directory. I am struggling with the directory part which would go after the `-o`

```
for i in *
    if [ "$i" = VARIABLE -o ]
    then
        continue
    fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if i is the variable"?  In the for loop, i is always the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the question, but a common idiom is:

```
for i in *; do
  if test -d "$i"; then continue; fi
  ...
done
```

If you also want to compare against a particular value, you really shouldn't use `-o`.  It's been deprecated for a long time.  Instead, use:

```
if test -d "$i" || test "$i" = VARIABLE; then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `test -d`:

```
if [ "$i" = VARIABLE ] || ! [ -d "$i" ]
then continue
fi
```

Or more succinctly:

```
[ "$i" != VARIABLE ] && [ -d "$i" ] || continue
```

Or as separate tests:

```
[ "$i" != VARIABLE ] || continue
[ -d "$i" ] || continue
```